# Changing the order of some words in a string

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, calloc

I've been trying to solve this exercise for a week now and my code doesn't work and I can't understand why and how to change it. The exercise is:
recieving a length from the user, then recieving a string (str) as long as 'length' and then recieving a number (int n) from the user.Then I need to execute the function 'void ReverseNumWords (char*str, int n).The function reverses the first n words in the string. For example: for 'I am your father StarWars' and n=3:
'your am I father StarWars'. It'll be right to assume that the words are separated by ' '. Thanks for the help!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void Reverse()
{

   int len,num;
   char *str;
   printf("Please enter how many chars to allocate:\n");
   //Asking from the user the length of a string.
   scanf("%d", &len);
   //Allocating memory for the string.
   str = (char*)calloc(len, sizeof(int));
   //Making sure the allocation was successful.
   if (!str)
       printf("Error: Cannot allocate Memory\n");
   printf("Allocated %d chars\n", len);
   printf("Please enter your string:\n");
   scanf("%s", str);
   printf("Please enter how many words to reverse:\n");
   scanf("%d", &num);
   ReverseNumWords(*str, num, len);
   free(str);
}

void ReverseNumWords(char*str, int num,int len)
{

   char *sub;
   char temp;
   //Allocating memory for the string.
   sub = (char*)calloc(len, sizeof(int));
   //Making sure the allocation was successful.
   if (!sub)
       printf("Error: Cannot allocate Memory\n");
   int i, j,l;
   i = j = 0;
   for (; i < len, j <= num; i++)
       if (str[i] == '\0' || str[i] == 0)
           j++;

   for (l = 0; l < i; l++)
       sub[i] = str[i];

   for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
       temp = sub[j];
       sub[j] = sub[i - (1+j)];
       sub[i - (1+j)] = sub[j];

   reverseWords(*sub);


}

void reverseWords(char *sub)
{

   char *word_begin = sub;
   char *temp = sub;

   while (*temp)
   {
      temp++;
      if (*temp == '\0')
      {
         reverse(word_begin, temp - 1);
      }
      else if (*temp == ' ')
      {
         reverse(word_begin, temp - 1);
         word_begin = temp + 1;
      }
   } 

   reverse(sub, temp - 1);
}

void reverse(char *begin, char*sub, char *end)
{

    char temp;
    while (begin < end)
    {
        temp = *begin;
        *begin++ = *end;
        *end-- = temp;
    }
    printf("%s\n", sub);
}
```

Comment: First of all, why are you using sizeof(int) to allocate chars?

Comment: you're right! changed it, the code still doesn't work...... I feel like there's a simple way to code this and instead I make it a lot more complicated..... any tips? can you show me what would you do to solve it successfully?

Comment: I'm working on your code now. My first though is to change the way you read it, I'll try read chars, and not a string. Wait a minute, pls

Comment: It gets segfault, and i'm trying to figure out why

Comment: Spent hours infront of VisualStudio and couldn't figure why the code doesn't work.......

Comment: oh, when you read with %s, it will stop when you find a ' '.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
str = (char*)calloc(len, sizeof(int));
```

This needs to be:

```
str = (char*)calloc(len, sizeof(char));
```

I also recommend maybe using [`malloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) to allocate memory for your strings, as you seem to be having trouble using `calloc()`.

You would use it like this:

```
char *str = malloc(len+1); /* Since sizeof(char) is 1, you don't need to include it */
```

This is also brings up the fact that you [Don't need to cast the result of malloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

It is good to see that your checking the return value of your allocations, that
's always a good thing.

### Another way to read strings:

Instead of using `scanf()` to read strings from `stdin`, you can use [`fgets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) instead.

> `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)` reads a line from an input stream, and copies the bytes over to `char *str`, which must be given a size of `n` bytes as a threshold of space it can occupy.

**Things to note about fgets:**

- Appends `\n` character at the end of buffer. Can be removed easily if you wish.
- On error, returns `NULL`. If no characters are read, still returns `NULL` at the end.
- Buffer must be given size `n`.
- Reads specified stream. Either from `stdin` or `FILE *`.

Here is an example of how it can be used to read a line of input from `stdin`:

```
char buffer[100]; /* statically declared buffer */

printf("Enter a string: ");
fgets(buffer, 100, stdin); /* read line of input into buffer. Needs error checking */
```

You can also use functions like [`strtok`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) and [`strcat`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm) to reverse and concatenate your strings.

### Here is an example program which n words in a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *allocate_chars(int *len);
void number_of_words(int *num);
void read_strings(char *str, int len);
char *reversed_words(char *str, int len, int num);
char *reverse_word(char *word);

int main(void) {
    int len, num;
    char *str, *result;

    str = allocate_chars(&len);

    read_strings(str, len);

    number_of_words(&num);

    result = reversed_words(str, len, num);
    printf("Reversed string = %s\n", result);

    free(result);
    free(str);

    return 0;
}

char *allocate_chars(int *len) {
    char *str;

    printf("Enter how many chars to allocate: ");
    if (scanf("%d", len) != 1 || *len < 1) {
        printf("Invalid length.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    getchar();

    str = malloc(*len+1);
    if (!str) {
        printf("Cannot allocate %d bytes for string.\n", *len+1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Allocated %d chars.\n", *len+1);

    return str;
}

void number_of_words(int *num) {
    printf("Please enter how many words to reverse: ");
    if (scanf("%d", num) != 1 || *num < 0) {
        printf("Invalid number.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void read_strings(char *str, int len) {
    int slen;

    printf("Please enter your string: ");
    if (fgets(str, len, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot create buffer.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    slen = strlen(str);
    if (slen > 0) {
        if (str[slen-1] == '\n') {
            str[slen-1] = '\0';
        } else {
            printf("Entered string bigger than buffer size of %d bytes.\n", len);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if (!*str) {
        printf("No string entered.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

char *reversed_words(char *str, int len, int num) {
    char *reversed, *word, *reversed_word;
    const char *delim = " ";
    int count = 1;

    reversed = malloc(len+1);
    if (!reversed) {
        printf("Cannot allocate %d bytes for string.\n", len+1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    *reversed = '\0';

    word = strtok(str, delim);
    while (word != NULL) {
        if (count <= num) {
            reversed_word = reverse_word(word);
            strcat(reversed, reversed_word);
            free(reversed_word);
            count++;
        } else {
            strcat(reversed, word);
        }
        word = strtok(NULL, delim);
        if (word != NULL) {
            strcat(reversed, delim);
        }
    }

    return reversed;
}

char *reverse_word(char *word) {
    char *reverse;
    int slen, str_count = 0, i;

    slen = strlen(word);

    reverse = malloc(slen+1);
    if (!reverse) {
        printf("Cannot allocate %d bytes for string.\n", slen+1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = slen-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse[str_count++] = word[i];
    }
    reverse[str_count] = '\0';

    return reverse;
}
```

Sample Input:

```
Enter how many chars to allocate: 50
Allocated 51 chars.
Please enter your string: Hello what a lovely day
Please enter how many words to reverse: 4
```

Output:

```
Reversed string = olleH tahw a ylevol day
```

Comment: After endless days I solved this exercise succesfully, yet my code is way more "messy" and long. Thank you for the explainations! I learned a lot from you.

Comment: @Cbeginner No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your read function, should be something like this

```
int len,num;
   char *str;
   printf("Please enter how many chars to allocate:\n");
   //Asking from the user the length of a string.
   scanf(" %d", &len);
   //Allocating memory for the string.
   str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
   //Making sure the allocation was successful.
   if (!str)
       printf("Error: Cannot allocate Memory\n");

   printf("Allocated %d chars\n", len);
   printf("Please enter your string:\n");
   scanf(" %[^\n]s", str);

   printf("Please enter how many words to reverse:\n");
   scanf(" %d", &num);
   ReverseNumWords(*str, num, len);
   free(str);
```

Because when reading with %s, you'll stop at the first ' ' (blank space) you find. And you want to read until you find a \n (enter).

Comment: Thank you for your help but it didn't solve the problem........ what about the other functions? do i need them or is there a shorter way to solve this exercise?

Comment: Yes, your ReverseNumWords isnt right also. Why you go through your string and add j by 1 when you fin \0 or 0? If after this you set j = 0?

Comment: What is the function of variable j in the first for-loop in ReverseNumWords?

Comment: oh, i dont know whether num><=len so I made two conditions so the loop would stop.

Comment: But you make j++ and dont use that after.